# Html inside Netsuite help tags

Tags: netsuite

I have a custom field in Netsuite to which I want to add html.

I am currently filling the field with:

```
<html>
<ul>
<li>text1</li>
<li>text2</li>
<li>text3</li>
</ul>
</html>
```

I can see that this works here in stackoverflow, but for Netsuite it does not get parsed and shows all the tags as hardcoded text. Does anyone know what I have to add so Netsuite parses the HTML correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can enter HTML in the help text field by beginning the markup with  and ending it with .  Because HTML tags are supported, use `&lt;` and `&gt;` to display the < less than and > greater than symbols in the custom field level help.  You can reference Suite Article [77032](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/77032/kw/77032)